# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when attempting to connect to NodeJS server running on a Docker Container in Windows 10

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I have an app that's contains a NodeJS server and a ReactJS client. The project's structure is as follows:

```
client
  Dockerfile
  package.json
  .
  .
  .
server
  Dockerfile
  package.json
  .
  .
  .
docker-compose.yml
.gitignore
```

To run both of these, I am using a `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  server:
    build: ./server
    expose:
      - 8000
    environment:
      API_HOST: "http://localhost:3000/"
      APP_SERVER_PORT: 8000
      MYSQL_HOST_IP: mysql
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
    command: yarn start
  client:
    build: ./client
    environment:
      REACT_APP_PORT: 3000
      NODE_PATH: src
    expose:
      - 3000
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./client/src:/app/src
      - ./client/public:/app/public
    links:
      - server
    command: yarn start
```

And inside of each of both the `client` and `server` folders I have a `Dockerfile` (same for each):

```
FROM node:10-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app
COPY yarn.lock /app
COPY . /app

RUN yarn install

CMD ["yarn", "start"]

EXPOSE 80
```

Where the client's `start` script is simply `react-scripts start`, and the server's is `nodemon index.js`. The client's `package.json` has a proxy that is supposed to allow it communication with the server:

```
"proxy": "http://server:8000",
```

The react app would call a component that looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function callServer() {
  axios.get('http://localhost:8000/test', {
    params: {
      table: 'sample',
    },
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  });
}

export function SampleComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      This is a sample component
      {callServer()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Which would call the `/test` path in the node server, as defined in the `index.js` file:

```js
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.listen(process.env.APP_SERVER_PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App server now listening on port ${process.env.APP_SERVER_PORT}`);
});

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hi');
});
```

Now, this code works like a charm when I run it on my Linux Mint machine, but when I run it on Windows 10 I get the following error (I run both on Chrome):

```
GET http://localhost:8000/test?table=sample net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Is it that I would need to run these on a different port or IP address? I read somewhere that the connections may be using a windows network instead of the network created by `docker-compose`, but I'm not even sure how to start diagnosing this. Please let me know if you have any ideas that could help.

**EDIT:** Here are the results of `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                            NAMES
1824c61bbe99        react-node-mysql-docker-boilerplate_client   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   react-node-mysql-docker-boilerplate_client_1
```

and here is `docker ps -a`. For some reason, it seems the server image stops by itself as soon as it starts

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS                            NAMES
1824c61bbe99        react-node-mysql-docker-boilerplate_client   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                 80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   react-node-mysql-docker-boilerplate_client_1
5c26276e37d1        react-node-mysql-docker-boilerplate_server   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 minutes ago       Exited (127) 3 minutes ago                                    react-node-mysql-docker-boilerplate_server_1
```

Comment: have you tried changing the port from 8000 to anything else?

Comment: Under which address do you call the original html page?

Comment: @gCoh I tried to make an axios get request to `localhost:3000` and change the server port to expose `3000` but I get the same thing

Comment: @mbuechmann The react app is supposed to use `localhost:3000`

Comment: Okay. And localhost:3000 is also the address you type in in your Chrome's address bar?

Comment: @mbuechmann yes

Comment: Could you do a `docker ps` on your console and write your results here?

Comment: @mbuechmann please see edit

Comment: When you start just the server with `docker-compose up server` you should see the log output. What dies it say?

Comment: @mbuechmann Thank you for bearing with me! As it turns out, I get the following `/bin/sh: nodemon: not found`. So the server would never start, causing the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. I guess that even though the images are built with the `yarn` command in the `Dockerfile` that's supposed to have everything, the server still depends on the `node_modules` folder, so all I did was go into the server folder, run `yarn install`, then run the images again and now everything works! Would you post this as an answer so that I may upvote it? Thanks again!